# Ruby sort_by of Objects/Classes undefined method 'sort_by' for

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a class Store, each Store have a Hash with differents Products and each Product have a Hash with differents kinds of sell.

```
class Store
    def initialize
        @store_products = Hash.new 
        #@store_products['product_id'] = Product
    end
end

class Product < Store
    def initialize(model)
        @model = model
        @sell_option = Hash.new 
        #@sell_option['sell_name'] = SellOption
    end
end

class SellOption < Product
    def initialize(size, price, stock)
        @size = size
        @price = price
        @stock = stock
    end
end
```

With this data:

```
product1 = Product.new("shirt1")
product1.add_sell_option(SellOption.new("S", 12, 10))
product1.add_sell_option(SellOption.new("M", 15, 10))
product1.add_sell_option(SellOption.new("L", 14, 10))

product2 = Product.new("shirt2")
product2.add_sell_option(SellOption.new("M", 6, 10))
product2.add_sell_option(SellOption.new("L", 7, 10))

product3 = Product.new("shirt2")
product3.add_sell_option(SellOption.new("M", 10, 10))
product3.add_sell_option(SellOption.new("L", 11, 10))
store = Store.new

store.add(product1)
store.add(product2)
store.add(product3)
```

In class Store I want to do a method that sort my Products by price.
If use this expression:

```
puts store.products_sorted_by_price

def products_sorted_by_price
    @store_products.each_value do |product| 
        product.sort_by{|k, v| v.value.price}
    end
end
```

Why it returns "undefined method 'sort_by' for Product..."!!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things I don't understand about your question:
 - Why does `Product` inherit from `Store`?
 - Why does `SellOption` inherit from `Product`?
 - Are you trying to sort products by price?
 - Which price do you use if the sell options have different prices?
 - Why do different sizes have different prices?
 - What is the `value` that you're extracting from the `v`, which is supposed to be a `Product`?

Anyway ... sort_by is typically run on an `Enumerable`, and `Product` isn't one, as far as I can see. So the precise answer is that Ruby says `undefined method 'sort_by' for Product` because you haven't defined `sort_by` on `Product`, or inherited from a class that does define it.

I am guessing you meant to do something more like this:

```
@store_products.sort_by {|k,v| v.value.price }?
```

Except even then, I don't know what `value` is, and you'll have to figure out how you want to deal with multiple prices in a product before you can really finish sort_by, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Clarify your question, and I can try to improve the answer.

Comment: Inherits; because I have more methods that needed.
From different prices, I have a method that choose the min price.
And my error was that I was not applying the order to the Product but to only one of them.